# Can't use Export() with Mathematica Trial Version

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Every time I try to use Export, I get this Error:

```
General::unavail: Export is not available in this version of Mathematica.
```

Why isn't Export() available with the Trial version?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might get a more authoritative answer from WRI.  As it stands, you'll just get comments like this one ... 'cos they don't want you to Export from the trial version.

Comment: Because it's a _trial_ version.

Comment: As an alternative, do `Put` or any of the `Write` functions work? While not as nice as `Export` you can usually cobble together something that will work as you expect from those functions.

Comment: I have an idea: `Export[]` among other things is supposed to be able to save *Mathematica* notebooks as well. In the older trial versions, it was an effective workaround for the trial version being disabled for saving notebooks. I guess they realized that, and decided to disable `Export[]` (as opposed to rewriting a version of `Export[]` for trial versions)...

Comment: I get that error (including the word Export) upon attempting to Import["http://example.com"], too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not an entirely unreasonable question if you're trying to see how Mathematica might integrate with a wider set of systems. Trial versions used to be save disabled and presumably this is still the case. Export makes a pretty useful workaround for that, so it too is knocked out.

Your choices are:

- Copy/paste and reformat. It's not hard to turn a nested list into a CSV. Copy/pasting graphics is easy too. None of this helps if you want to do this programatically, however.
- Try rcollyer's `Put`/`Write`.
- Pony up $295 for the Home Edition (or somewhat less for Student, if you qualify.)
- You could also try using the `Run` command:

`cmd = "echo " <> ToString[{{your}, {data}, {here}}] <> " | cat - >> output.dat"`
`Run[cmd]`

Replace that `ToString[...]` with any expression you have. This won't work for graphics but perhaps there's another way there? Raw bitmap data maybe. EDIT: Yes, use eg `ImageData[your_img, "Byte"]` to get a byte array of 0..255 RGB values out. ImageData supports a few types and interleaving, so your downstream program should be able to read it back in.

Comment: You can always output graphics as Table [{channel ,{i,1,3}] applied to Rasterize for an RGB type. There should be  suitable backend on the other side ....

Comment: Using Run worked for me in my evaluation copy.  Great idea!  Create a myExport function for convenience sake. (Unfortunately you cannot overwrite the built-in Export function as it is a protected symbols.)